# Softlayer API: Global IP Routing not working with ipv6

Tags: rest, ipv6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are setting up automatic failover for our ipv4/ipv6 global ip's. I can set the route for the ipv4 just fine by executing a get:

https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/xxxx/route/111.111.111.111/

But when I try the ipv6: 
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/xxxx/route/2607:f0d0:1e01:1a2::3/

I get this error:

```
{
   "error": "The selected destination IP address is currently not in tracking for subnet '2607:f0d0:0003:0023:0000:0000:0000:0000/64'.",
   "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to send the EndPointIpAddress without compress (no compressed form), so you should send like this:

```
https://api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/xxxx/route/2607:f0d0:1e01:01a2:0000:0000:0000:0003
```

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global::route](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress_Global/route)

Comment: I will recommend this to add in doc